# ストーリーボードで設定したアトリビュートを残してUILabelの文字列のみを変更したい

Tags: swift, ios

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166899/1979953
と
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297423/1979953

を参考に

```
extension UILabel {
    func replaceAttributedText(string: String) {
        if let originalAttributedText = self.attributedText {
            let attributes = originalAttributedText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

を作ってみたのですが、`空文字`を与えた後で

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'`

になります。

つまり

```
self.hogeLabel.replaceAttributedText(string: "hoge")
self.hogeLabel.replaceAttributedText(string: "")
self.hogeLabel.replaceAttributedText(string: "aaa") // 空文字を与えてしまった後なのでエラー
```

このようなコードでエラーが発生します。

`空文字`を与えたことによってアトリビュート情報が吹っ飛んでしまったせいなのかと推測しているのですが、うまく文字列だけ入れ替える方法はないのでしょうか？

（`空文字`ではなくて、スペースなどの`空白文字`を入れるとうまくいくのですが、`空文字`を入れたいです）

Comment: 一旦空文字列が入れられたら、`attributes(at:...)`で設定されたあトリビュートを取り出すことはできない、と言うのが現在の`NSAttributedString`の実装のようです。「空文字列を入れたい」と言う要件があるならば、掲載されたextensionは使えない、と思って他の方法を探された方が良いように思います。

Answer (score 0):

コメントしたように現在の`NSAttributeString`の実装では(空文字列を代入したい、と言う前提のもとで)掲載されたextensionは使えない、と言うことになります。

ここでは、「他の方法」のひとつとして、「ストーリーボードで設定したアトリビュートを残して文字列のみを変更」出来るようなカスタムLabelクラスをお示ししておきます。

```
import UIKit

class AttrLabel: UILabel {
    //ストーリーボードで設定されたアトリビュートを保存しておくインスタンスプロパティ
    var attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [:]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        //Xib/Storyboardからインスタンス化された時に設定されたアトリビュートを保存しておく
        if let attrText = self.attributedText, attrText.length > 0 {
            attributes = attrText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
        }
    }

    //`text`プロパティを操作すると、保存されたアトリビュートを使って、文字列だけを変更する
    override var text: String? {
        get {
            return super.text
        }
        set {
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: newValue ?? "",
                                                     attributes: self.attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

普通にストーリーボードに配置したLabelのCustom Classを上記の`AttrLabel`に付け替えればすぐに使えます。

少なくともこの程度の単純な例なら

```
        self.hogeLabel.text = "hoge"
        self.hogeLabel.text = ""
        self.hogeLabel.text = "aaa"
```

元のアトリビュートを保存したまま、文字列だけ入れ替えられるのが確認できると思います。

---

本当にやりたいことは何なのか考えて、ひとつのやり方に縛られずに考えれば、もっと良い方法があるかもしれません。上の例も含めて、ぜひあれこれ試してみてください。